# Singing with speech synthesis

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I want my program can sing like cortana do(You are my sunshine) but it seems to read the song. I have use Microsoft Eva Mobile(Cortana voice) but unchanged. Any solutions? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in other way, Cortana does not sing songs which you desire, there are limited songs so in the same way, if you want to create an application like Cortana then simply record your own voice and edit it to sound like cortana and then put the recorded (.wav) file in resources and whenever user asks your virtual assistant app to sing a song for him/her then you simply trigger your recorded (.wav) files randomly.

Comment: I record her voice with Windows WASAPI and play it!